# string replacement using search pattern

Tags: bash, scripting, sed, awk

I am new to scripting.

Currently i got struck with one issue.

The input string:

```
hw=ABC host=*-0 vrt=se6w
hw=ABC host=*-1 vrt=se6w
```

required output:

```
hw=ABC host=SE-0 vrt=se6w
hw=ABC host=SE-1 vrt=se6w
```

here * can be any value.

- means the value is dynamic. we dont know what could be there in advance. I just want to replace anything that comes in host filed with SE.  for ex: host=xxxx-0 with SE-0 and

yyyy-1 with SE-1.    ie.,the value after "-1/0" should remain same....

Comment: `I got stuck` -- what did you try?

Comment: `we need to replace host value if it is CFPU-0/ESPU-0` What is `CFPU-0/ESPU-0` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat file
hw=ABC host=*-0 vrt=se6w
hw=ABC host=*-1 vrt=se6w

$ sed 's/\(host=\)[^-]*/\1SE/' file
hw=ABC host=SE-0 vrt=se6w
hw=ABC host=SE-1 vrt=se6w
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed` is your friend! To replace `CFPU-0` or `ESPU-0` by `SE-0` you may write:

```
# Create a testfile
sylvain@daal:/tmp$ cat << EOF > testfile
hw=ABC host=CFPU-0 vrt=se6w
hw=ABC host=ESPU-0 vrt=se6w
hw=ABC host=ESPU-1 vrt=se6w
hw=ABC host=XXXX-0 vrt=se6w
EOF

# Perform substitution using sed
sylvain@daal:/tmp$ sed 's/host=\(CFPU\|ESPU\)-0/host=SE-0/' < testfile
hw=ABC host=SE-0 vrt=se6w
hw=ABC host=SE-0 vrt=se6w
hw=ABC host=ESPU-1 vrt=se6w
hw=ABC host=XXXX-0 vrt=se6w
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure awk will also do the trick :

```
awk -F'=| ' '{print $1"="$2" "$3"="( $4 =="CFPU-0"||$4 =="ESPU-0" ? "SE-0" : $4 )" "$5"="$6}' file
```

If the string is stored as a variable, you can do a echo and pipe the awk command above, like this :

```
echo $variable | awk -F'=| ' '{......}'
```

Answer (score -1):

Use sed for output of echo your string and replace the pattern as per your requirement as following script:

```
x="hw=ABC host=*-0 vrt=se6w
hw=ABC host=*-1 vrt=se6w"
x=`echo $x | sed 's/\*-/SE-/g'`
echo "x : $x"
```

Comment: `"here * can be any value"`

Comment: * means the value is dynamic. we dont know what could be there in advance. I just want to replace anything that comes in host filed with SE..  for ex: host=xxxx-0 with SE-0 and yyyy-1 with SE-1.    ie.,the value after "-1/0" should remain same....